# ZK Bubble Chart Label Plotting issue

Tags: highcharts, zk

I am using [ZK bubble chart](http://www.zkoss.org/zkchartsdemo/bubble) to show Popular and least products. It is working fine but I need to show particular product name on above of each bubble. In Zk bubble chart they had divided bubbles into 3 sections (for example series1, series2, series3). So If some one hover on any bubble it will show same series label respectively.

I want to bind some of products in popular series and some of products in least series. So that if some one hover on any of bubble he can understand to which product that bubble is representing. Thats why I want to add product Name label in each bubble. Is it possible ?

Comment: You can use datalabels: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.enabled

Comment: Can I use this highchart api over ZK framework ? Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: One more thing I don't want to plot label on X Y axis. I want labels on Bubble.

Comment: I guess that you contact with the authors of ZK wrapper